# JavaScript Object instantiation within another Object methods

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I'm trying to figure out how to handle the situation, where you have several objects under the same namespace, where methods of all of them might be used interchangeably - i.e. first object might be using methods from the second one and the second one from the first. Both might also use other objects etc. It's best to represent it with an example:

```
var MySystem = MySystem || {};

MySystem.Form = function() {};

MySystem.Form.prototype = {

    objErrorHandler : null,
    objHelper : null,
    objValidation : null,

    idClickSubmit : '.submitClick',

    getAttributes : function(thisForm) {

        "use strict";

        if (this.objValidation.isEmpty(thisForm)) {

            return {};

        }

    },

    submit : function() {

        "use strict";

        var self = this;

        $(document).on(
            'click',
            self.idClickSubmit,
            self.objErrorHandler.tryCatch(function(event) {

                self.objHelper.preventDefaultPropagation(event);

                var thisTarget = $(this).data('target');

                $('form[data-identity="' + thisTarget + '"]').submit();

            })
        );

    },

    dynamicRow : function() {

        "use strict";

        var objFormDynamicRow = new MySystem.FormDynamicRow();
        objFormDynamicRow.init();

    },

    init : function() {

        "use strict";

        var self = this;

        self.objErrorHandler = new CMDSystem.ErrorHandler();
        self.objHelper = new CMDSystem.Helper();
        self.objValidation = new CMDSystem.Validation();

        self.objErrorHandler.tryCatch(function() {

            self.submit();
            self.dynamicRow();

        })(self);

    }

};
```

Now - to instantiate this object I would use:

```
var objForm = new MySystem.Form();
objForm.init();
```

The problem is that Validation object might make use of the getAttributes() method of the Form object and I would either instantiate it within Validation.init() method or within the method that would be calling it.

Now, the question here is - would I be better instantiating all additional objects (ErrorHandler, Helper and Validation) within each method that requires it (as private objects) or is the above approach correct and what are the benefits / drawbacks of using either approach.

Comment: Are you just asking what the benefits of [lazy initialisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) are?

Comment: I'm just not sure whether using the init() method which instantiates all other objects that are used within the class is the right way to do things - I'm coming from PHP background and to be fair I'm still confused with many aspects of JS.

Comment: Actually, you should put object initialisation (if you don't plan to only do it later) right inside the constructor function, i.e. `MySystem.Form`. No extra `init` method.

Comment: How is this going to work when Validation will need Form instance as well - will it not cause any problems even though some methods from within the constructor will use binding to some events etc.?

Comment: No, what problems would it cause?

Comment: Wouldn't repetitive binding be problematic here?

Comment: I don't exactly see what you mean by "repetitive binding", but putting the code in the constructor and only calling `new MySystem.Form();` is no different from `(new MySystem.Form()).init()`

Comment: Please have a look at the init() method - it calls submit(), which binds click event to the dom element. By putting everything to the constructor it will execute this binding every time the class is instantiated.

Comment: Yes, isn't that what is intended? You say yourself that "*to instantiate this object I would use: `var objForm = new MySystem.Form(); objForm.init();`*"